# Where are mother's earrings?

Tags: lucius

In the game [Lucius](http://store.steampowered.com/app/218640) you get asked by your mother find her earrings. She does not give you any hint where it might be. Searching the mansion so far was without any success.

Where are the earrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earrings can be found in Jovita's bedroom in the servant living quarters, on the middle level, eastern wing.

Source: http://lucius.wikia.com/wiki/Chore_-_Find_earrings